# Filter a pandas dataframe based on value in a list of dictionary in column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, apply

Hi a pandas data frame and one of its columns its a list of dictionaries. See below:

#### Example for the first row

```
df.iloc[0].colexample 

[{'status': 'married',
  'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 6, 27, 31, 118000)},
 {'status': 'divorced',
  'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 6, 27, 52, 47000)},
 {'status': 'sent',
'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 6, 27, 52, 47000)},
{'status': 'other',
'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 6, 27, 52, 47000)}]
```

I would want to filter the dataframe by keeping only rows that it's **colexample** has status == other or status == sent

In this example, I'd keep this row but there are others that have different values for status

Comment: Normally you want (more or less) atomic values in each cell of a dataframe. In this case, I'd try to `.explode` the lists into separate rows, then split the dictionaries into a `status` and a `date` column. Then you can filter by `status` easily.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
df['check']=df['colexample'].apply(lambda x: True if any(i in ['other','sent'] for i in [item for sublist in [[list(i.values()) for i in x]][0]for item in sublist]) else False)
df=df[df['check']==True]
```

Details:

```
#for each row it loops through the list and takes all the values ​​in dictionary and puts them in a list.

values = [item for sublist in [[list(i.values()) for i in a]][0]for item in sublist] 
#where a is the value in the row.
print(values)
'''
['married', datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 6, 27, 31, 118000), 'divorced', datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 6, 27, 52, 47000), 'sent', datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 6, 27, 52, 47000), 'other', datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 6, 27, 52, 47000)]
'''

#then define filter list:
filter_list=['other','sent']

#compare this two lists and return True if a match is found like this:
if any(i in filter_list for i in [item for sublist in [[list(i.values()) for i in a]][0]for item in sublist]):
```